# How 2D to 3D conversion is performed?

Tags: video, editing, effects, 3d

The Oscar winning movie [Titanic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titanic_(1997_film))

which was picturized  in 2D format and released in 1997 . It was again released in 3D format in 2012.

But I wonder that how 2D to 3D conversion of movie frames is performed. So can anybody explain about it? What factors (like depth ) should be taken into consideration for 2D to 3D  conversion?

Answer (score 2):

They've done it via [rotoscoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotoscoping) techniques in order to create depth information.

From fxguide.com about [Titanic 3d Conversion](http://www.fxguide.com/featured/art-of-stereo-conversion-2d-to-3d-2012/):

> The team at [Stereo D](http://www.stereodllc.com/) used no projection or automated solutions. The team isolated with multiple layers of roto each of the key elements of the scene, often many per person in the foreground and then these were used to derive a depth map. From the depth map normally a new left and right eye was created.

Also see the wikipedia article about [3d Stereo Conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2D_to_3D_conversion) and [The Art of Stereo Conversion](http://www.fxguide.com/featured/art-of-stereo-conversion-2d-to-3d-2012/).